# What is a Quick and Understandable PROCMAIL Way of Allowing POP Mailbox users to turn on and off Vaction AutoReply

Tags: linux, email, email-server, procmail

I've just inherited an Undocumented Linux File and Mail Server.  In the past week, I audited and discovered several things that had been neglected for a while (logins still active but for long gone employees, etc).  I fixed and documented these....

I also discovered that people have gotten used to having 'IT' turn on and *off vacation auto reply* for email accounts (via .procmailrc ).  I do not consider controlling one's *vacation auto reply* to be an administrative tasks and I seek to quickly put this under user control.

Can someone help me grasp onto an approach to automate this feature?  (*Difficulty: I'm not very familiar with procmail*)

Comment: do they have user accounts in the mail server?

Comment: Yes, they do.  At this time, All email users have local logins.

Comment: Which mail server are you using?

Comment: From the looks of it, it is sendmail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [usermin](http://www.webmin.com/usermin.html). It is web-based, intended for end-users and can be used to edit .procmailrc files and set up mail forwarding and auto-replies (and much more).

BTW, if you just want vacation auto-replies, I think you could also use the [vacation](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/vacation.1.php) program.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's a GUI procmail rule builder:

http://www.uvm.edu/opensource/?Page=procbuilder.html

Haven't used it, but looks promising...

You might also consider installing a webmail package, such as [SquirrelMail](http://www.squirrelmail.org/). It has plugins for autoreplies.